# Unexpected value null imported by the module t

Tags: angular, heroku

I got this strange issue when deploying my  app (a fork of angular2-express-starter) to Heroku. https://totalautosapp.herokuapp.com/
At first i thought it was Heroku, but I've deployed it to netlify and same happens.

It says:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'null' imported by the module 't'
```

Yes, there are a lot of similar questions that allowed me to understand the issue a lot better, but what blinds me is the module 't'. What module is it referring to?

And most of the questions state that the unexpected value is 'undefined', not 'null'. which brings me the idea that it is importing a null module, but still don't know which one is doing that, even when it works in devEnvironment.

Here's my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.router';
import { effects, store, instrumentation } from './store';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    store,
    effects,
    routing,
    instrumentation
  ],
   bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And if anyone would take a deep look, here's my shared module: https://codeshare.io/adKKz5

Any help would be well appreciated.

EDIT:

Using console.log I was able to compare outputs from my local build and the heroku one. So I detected that the null module is StoreDevToolsModule from ngrx/store-devtools.

This output is from local run in the line console.log(instrumentation)

```
Object { ngModule: StoreDevtoolsModule(), providers: Array[3] }
```

And this one from heroku

```
null  main.d61dd7a248d9bbd30ca6.bundle.js:1:5868
```

`Error: Unexpected value 'null' imported by the module 't'`

Comment: You can do a `console.log(yourModules);` to see which one is null before the `@NgModule`

Comment: Thanks, where specifically should I do this?

Comment: After imports for example

Comment: Thanks. I'll try when I get home and get you know.

Comment: I added information about the null module

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was having the same issue, it was caused because my NgModules classes had the "export default" modifier. Look if your modules had the export default and remove the "default" modifier as it's not supported by ngc.

Comment: kudos for the answer you spare me a lot of sweat :p

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem when I wanted to build my project by `npm run build`
I searched for many solutions, but in the none of them helped. The problem's solution was easy!

I am using `ng-lazyload-image` and I imported it without curly braces. After adding them around `LazyLoadImageModule` vuala it worked. Will be happy if this will help somebody.

**Problem**:

```
import LazyLoadImageModule from 'ng-lazyload-image';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LazyLoadImageModule,
....]
})
```

**Solution**:

```
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LazyLoadImageModule,
....]
})
```