# TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertNoMembers' of null

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

In Ionic I'm having an issue while executing the following command:

> ionic cordova build ios --prod

After that, in "ngc started" the following message appears:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertNoMembers' of null
at AotSummaryResolver.resolveSummary (/dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31986:21)
at CompileMetadataResolver._loadSummary (/dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14710:66)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (/dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15742:66)
at /dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14904:76
at Array.map (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (/dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14904:22)
at /dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29359:88
at Array.forEach (native)
at AotCompiler.findGeneratedFileNames (/dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29358:25)
at Object.findGeneratedFileNames (/dir/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:392:82)
```

Command without "--prod" works fine. Also "ionic serve" works fine

Comment: try `ionic package build ios --prod` or `ionic package build android --profile=prod --release --prod` https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/package/build/

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: is `assertNoMembers` code you wrote...do you recognize that variable?

Comment: No, I think it's part of @angular/compiler

Comment: Found a solution to my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604461/unexpected-value-null-imported-by-the-module-t)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error this morning, for me the problem was that I had something like this in one of my module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  entryComponents: components.filter(x => x.entryComponent)],
})
```

entryComponents should be an array of type so that the compiler could resolve it at compile time. Changing it to solve the problem:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  entryComponents: [MyComponent],
})
```

Note: if you ran into this problem with ng serve, the error usually disappear when you change a file and angular recompile your project.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not my case. I still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a variant of [Simon's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731805/2831961). The fix was identical by extension.

```
// sidenavs is an object with keys and values, and values() is a lodash method that extracts only the values, which are components in this case
const mySidenavs = values(sidenavs)

@NgModule({
   imports: [...],
   declarations: [...],
   entryComponents: [
    // Spread operator breaks
    ...mySidenavs
   ]
})
```

Simply importing each individually fixed the AOT build.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [...],
   declarations: [...],
   entryComponents: [
      Sidenav1,
      ...
      SidenavN
   ]
})
```