# ERROR on build: unexpected value null exported by the module

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I'm getting this error during the Angular Build (ng build --prod):

> ERROR in: Unexpected value 'null' exported by the module 'SharedModule'

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [InputComponent, InputSimpleComponent, ModelEditComponent,
               ModelEditSaveButtonComponent, ModelSelectTableHeaderComponent,
               ModelEditActionsComponent, ModelSelectTableBodyComponent,
               ModelSelectTablePageComponent, ModelSelectTopComponent,
               ModelSelectTableComponent, ModelSelectFilterComponent,
               ModelSelectFilterSearchButtonComponent,
               MakesAutocompleteComponent, ModelsAutocompleteComponent,
               VersionsAutocompleteComponent,
               VersionsYearsAutocompleteComponent,
               StatusAutocompleteComponent, FormsAutocompleteComponent,
               BannersGroupAutocompleteComponent,
               BannersStatusAutocompleteComponent,
               EntitiesAutocompleteComponent,
               MetaDatasGroupsAutocompleteComponent,
               ContentsGroupAutocompleteComponent,
               ContentsTypeAutocompleteComponent/*,
               ModelSelectTableRowComponent*/],
imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule,
          MatAutocompleteModule, MatInputModule],
exports: [InputComponent, InputSimpleComponent, FormsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, ModelEditComponent,
          ModelEditSaveButtonComponent, ModelSelectTableHeaderComponent,
          ModelEditActionsComponent, ModelSelectTableBodyComponent,
          ModelSelectTablePageComponent, ModelSelectTopComponent,
          ModelSelectTableComponent, ModelSelectFilterComponent,
          ModelSelectFilterSearchButtonComponent, MakesAutocompleteComponent,
          ModelsAutocompleteComponent, VersionsAutocompleteComponent,
          VersionsYearsAutocompleteComponent, MatAutocompleteModule,
          MatInputModule, StatusAutocompleteComponent,
          FormsAutocompleteComponent, BannersGroupAutocompleteComponent,
          BannersStatusAutocompleteComponent, EntitiesAutocompleteComponent,
          MetaDatasGroupsAutocompleteComponent,
          ContentsGroupAutocompleteComponent,
          ContentsTypeAutocompleteComponent/*,
          ModelSelectTableRowComponent*/]})
export class SharedModule {}
```

It works fine during the **development build**:

> ng build --configuration=development

But the error happens during the **production build**:

> ng build --configuration=production **OR** ng build --prod

The closest solution I've found is this one:

> ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false

However, these options disables the Angular build optimization :/

I'm using Angular 6.0.1 / Angular CLI 6.0.8. I've already searched but haven't found a definitive answer. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: What you can do is remove each export either one by one or by batch to determine which component is having a null value. You can even remove all exports to verify that it is the cause of the issue. If this is a public repository maybe you give me access or let me fork the repo so that I can debug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604461/unexpected-value-null-imported-by-the-module-t

Answer (score 1):

I  had the same error when I had:

```
export default class SomeComponent {...}
```

Changing it to:

```
export class SomeComponent {...}
```

has fixed the problem